# import a vanilla javascript module file to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

iam coming from a vanilla javascript developer

i need to import a javascript file that is totally vanilla javascript

it's a module that contains 2500 lines of code

i have imported the javascript file inside the index.html cfile

```
  <body>
    <script src="src/views/pages/Customers/eidatoolkit.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

When initiating the code inside the react i got the following error

```
 Line 188:21:  'Toolkit' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here is my implementation

```
var ToolkitOB = new Toolkit(
  onOpenHandlerCB, /* reference to onOpen call back function */
  closeHandlerCB, /* reference to onClose call back function */
  errorHandlerCB, /* reference to onError call back function */
  options /* options */
);
```

trying to export the Toolkit function is leading to 100 errors when compiling

Comment: are you using `create-react-app` for react apps?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Yes

Comment: Just like you use `import React from 'react'` , you should also be importing your Toolkit inside the React file.

Comment: `import Toolkit from "src/views/pages/Customers/eidatoolkit.js"` Something like this should work if you have exported Toolkit from that file.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Doesn't work . this produces several errors of undefined variables and inproper use of self

Comment: Could you replicate your issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react)?

Comment: How do you import? Are you not exporting?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/pages/Customers/eidatoolkit.js"></script>.Hope this helps

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá done , please don't share this link becuase this module is private module Better if you transfer it to private

Comment: @d-saurabh returning toolkit is not defined

Comment: where is the link? You should be sending me the link?

Comment: @AhmedAhmedSayed ,Just give a try in CodeSandBox or other online IDE .may be some issues in your env.

Comment: @d-saurabh  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6upmy1?file=src%2Feidatoolkit.js

Comment: @PrateekThapa https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6upmy1?file=src%2Feidatoolkit.js